# Customization tableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-controls

How I can add a bar with 3 `UIButtons` above a `UITableView`? Please, I need examples. I want to make it [like this](http://rghost.net/42163545.view).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cell in your storyboard that contains a segment controller on it.

Now in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can dequeue that cell for the first on in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad`, create a `UIView` with a clear background colour.

Then, create a `UISegmentedControl` and add that as a `subview` to the clear view.

Finally, set your clear view as the table header view:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myClearView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bar is called as segmented control in iPhone.
To create it sub class UIViewControl class and add segmented control on top and then add UITableView below that better you can use Xib or you can find Coordinates and add both controls programatically.

refer to [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

you can do by implementing `Header View Section` delegate methods for your `UITableView` in your `ViewController`
In the following delegate method, give the size of your view you want to implement

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 60.0f;
}
```

Implement `UISegmentedControl` to get your three buttons and implement that in your `viewForHeaderInSection` method

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:segments] autorelease];
      segmentedControl.frame =  GRectMake(60, 10, 200, 40);
      ........
      // Do other Stuffs of Segmented Control
      ........
     return segmentedControl;
}
```